# Hamiltonian in SUSY (SUSY algebra)

Tags: supersymmetry

I was reading the book *Supersymmetry, Theory, Experiment and Cosmology* by P. Binétruy, and on page 25 the author goes from

$$ 1)[Q_r,Q_t]_+ \gamma^{0}_{ts}=2\gamma^{\mu}_{rs}P_{\mu} $$ $$ 2)\mbox{Contracting with $ \gamma^{0}_{sr}$,  } \sum_{r,t}[Q_r,Q_r]_{+}(\gamma^{02})_{tr} = 2Tr(\gamma^{0}\gamma^{\mu})P_{\mu} $$
$$ 3) \sum_{r}Q^{2}_{r}=4P^{0}$$
$$ 4) H=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{r}Q^{2}_{r} $$

I don't really understand how to go from stage 1 to 2 or 3 to 4, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step from 1 to 2 is: multiply by $\gamma^0$ and trace over the result.

2->3: $Tr((\gamma^0)^2)=Tr(1)=1$ on the left hand side and $2Tr(\gamma^0\gamma^\mu)P_\mu=8\eta^{0\mu}P_\mu=8P_0=8P^0$ on the right hand side.
Moreover the anticommutator gives $2Q_r^2$ so you can just strip off a factor of 2 on both sides.

3->4: $P^0$ is the total energy by definition, as the right hand side is in fact mulitplied by an unit operator (as $Q$ are operators) one has $P^0 1 = H$ giving the final result.

For some magic involving the gamma matrices see the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices

Comment: Am i correct in thinking that $[Q_r,Q_t]_+ = 0$ if r doesn't equal t?